# Regex break words instead of matching entire words

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the function below to linkify usernames that:

- start with a letter a-z or number 0-9
- contains letters a-z, numbers 0-9 and "-"
- have a length of 2-50 characters.

.

```
function linkifyUsernames(text){
return text.replace(/@\b([0-9a-z-]{2,49})\b/ig, 
"<a href='/profile/$1' target='_blank'>@$1</a>");
}
```

The function above works OK but the only problem is that it breaks words. For example,

**@abcdéíú**

The function linkifies the first part of the word

**[@abcd](http://www.mydomain/profile/abcd)éíú**

but I need a function that does not convert to links any words that start with @ but contains other characters than a-z0-9-. So, the word **@abcdéíú** must stay untauched.

Word bondaries for some reason don't help.

Comment: They don't work because JS regex is not Unicode-aware. You may use [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/api/) though.

Comment: An [XRegExp solution](http://jsfiddle.net/8odz5yz3/) without word boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function linkifyUsernames(text) {
  var pattern = /^(@)(\w{2,12})/ig;
  if(text.match(pattern).length>0 && text.match(pattern)[0]=== text)
     return text.replace(pattern, "<a href='/profile/$2' target='_blank'>@$2</a>");
  else return text;
}

$('div').append(linkifyUsernames('@abcd'))
$('div').append('<br/>')
$('div').append(linkifyUsernames('@abcdéáú'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
</div>
```

The `a-z` will not cover the special characters like **à,é**.

You can simplify using `\w` notation like:

> /^(@)(\w{2,12})/ig

Here example:
https://regex101.com/r/nZ7uI7/1

Comment: in my function this regex has the same problems.

Comment: check your js, I'm sure this regex will work for your case @Gigante

Comment: sorry, but you didn't understand my question. I want to linkify the following nicknames: "@nickname" "@nick-name" "@1nickname" and I DON'T want to linkify: "@nicéýúāē" I want it to keep untauched (the whole word) even if it starts with allowed characters because other characters are not 0-9a-z-. The problem is that the script takes first part "@nic" and converts to a link, leaving characters "éýúāē" uninked.

Comment: @Gigante I think I get it. Please checkout my new answer

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't fall between the `[0-9a-z]` range, try this range `[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]`, shown in the following example:
https://regex101.com/r/vW2mR9/1

Comment: This have the same problem as described in my question. Plus it does not linkify usernames that start with a number. And one more problem, in "@user-name" it linkify only first part "@user"

Comment: Sorry for that, I will fix my answer: `[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC0-9\-]` - https://regex101.com/r/vW2mR9/2 - is it better now?

Comment: Thanks for update but it still linkifies words that contain characters other than a-z0-9-. Instead of ignoring words like "@abcdéíú" it linkifies first part "@abcd"

Answer (score 0):

As stated on: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a    word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last    character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,    where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

If you try your sample string

> @abcdéíú

with just a `\w` which is meant to match any word character you'll see that `déíú`are not word characters in regex word. So even if you use this `[a-z\u00E0-\u00FC]` from the prev answer the regex fail due to `\b`.